# how to query mysql database table for the characters: â€.?

Tags: mysql, encoding

After a conversion process and migration, I ended up with some content being converted improperly where `'` was converted into a `â€`. For example: the word :`World's` was converted into `worldâ€s`.
This happened for a very few select posts. In the database the characters were saved as:
Strangely enough when I copy paste the value from the terminal it is `worldâ€` but the output as I am looking at it is:

[image]

The table description is:

```
bundle  varchar(128)    NO  MUL     
deleted tinyint(4)  NO  PRI 0   
entity_id   int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    
revision_id int(10) unsigned    NO  MUL NULL    
langcode    varchar(32) NO  PRI     
delta   int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    
field_art_content_value longtext    NO      NULL    
field_art_content_format    varchar(255)    YES MUL NULL
```

I tried to do a select with `field_art_content_value like` â€` but the terminal is not returning anything. How do I properly query for those characters?

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. Looks like a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python):  `"’ ‛".encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'â€™ â€›'`. The characters are `‘` (U+2018,  *Left Single Quotation Mark*) and  `’` (U+2019,  *Right Single Quotation Mark*). Read and follow [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) and [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/)…

Comment: Actually I was able to execute a like query in mysql. I copy and pasted the characters. MAC warned me that I am pasting with control character and I clicked proceed "paste". And it worked. I got all affected ids. the query was:
`select entity_id from node__field_art_content  where  field_art_content_value like '%â€%' collate utf8_bin;`.

Comment: `â€™` Mojibake for `’`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: I am sure it's related. In my case, it was peculiar. In my screenshot you see the char `â` .  However, to its right there appear to be 2 hidden characters. Not empty space but `control characters`. When I put the cursor on it, and move, I hit the right button 2 times for it to move. The other question definitly list steps to troubleshoot this by looking at the hex code. Thx